# Magento Module translations 1.9.3.0 problem

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I am trying to translate a module for a few languages. I don't want to use inline translations because every person which is using module will have to change translations in theirs database, so I found method where I can create translation.csv file and put it in my extension package.

I want to translate labels in admin configuration panel, and after lecture of a few articles about translations, I've added this code inside  tag in config.xml:

```
<translate>
    <modules>
        <SalesManago_Tracking>
            <files>
                <default>SalesManago_Tracking.csv</default>
            </files>
        </SalesManago_Tracking>
    </modules>
</translate>
```

And then I created SalesManago_Tracking.csv files in two places:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/fr_FR/ (for example)
app/locale/fr_FR/

After that I've added translation for one of labels:

```
<api_secret translate="label">
       <label>Api secret</label>
       <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
       <sort_order>20</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</api_secret>
```

So I've put a line in my csv file:"Api secret","Check translations!"

Looks ok, but when I change locale to France it doesn't work...
Can someone please tell me, what am I doing wrong ?
Thx!
(I turned off every of caches )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure ...

- your config node is not a child of `<frontend>` but of `<adminhtml>`.
- you set your backend locale to the language in question (dropdown at the bottom).
- really ALL caches are disabled including configuration cache.

The following setup worked for me - the option apparently shows under "Checkout" configuration for testing purposes:

**app/code/local/SalesManago/Tracking/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SalesManago_Tracking>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </SalesManago_Tracking>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <SalesManago_Tracking>
                    <files>
                        <default>SalesManago_Tracking.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </SalesManago_Tracking>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/SalesManago/Tracking/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <checkout>
            <groups>
                <options>
                    <fields>
                        <api_secret translate="label">
                            <label>Api secret</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </api_secret>
                    </fields>
                </options>
            </groups>
        </checkout>
    </sections>
</config>
```

**app/locale/fr_FR/SalesManago_Tracking.csv**

```
"Api secret","TEST"
```

Comment: It is a child of <adminhtml>, do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Ok it's my mistake... Case sensitive... I'va called my files Salesmanago_tracking but I should SalesManago...

Comment: Or you could switch to a case-insensitive filesystem ;)